# CSRF protection with NUXT, Axios, NEST and CSURF

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, csrf, nestjs, csrf-token

I've been googling for a while now, but still cannot get working CSURF CSRF protection between my NestJS app and my Nuxt SSR frontend.

Currently I have this implementation in my Nest main.js:

```
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.csrfToken();
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
    next();
  });
```

I'm not sure this is te correct way but I found this solution so far. The `token` variable is changing every request. In my understanding `req.cookie` sets this token to a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` which should be available at my client.

In my Nuxt application I created a plugin:

```
export default function ({ $axios, $cookies }) {
  $axios.onRequest(() => {
    const token = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    $axios.defaults.headers.common['x-xsrf-token'] = token
  })
}
```

There are two behaviour here:

1. The `token` is get from the cookie but once this is happen it stay the same for all requets - of course I get `invalid csrf token` error
2. The other case is when the `token` is `undefined`.

My question is how can be implemented a secure csrf protection between this libraries?

Additional info:
`$cookies` is from library `cookie-universal-nuxt` lib
and I also set `withCredentials: true` on axios calls:

```
await this.$axios.patch(`endpoint`, {}, { withCredentials: true })
```